# conditional probability : probability of $B$ knowing $\overline A$

Tags: probability

is there a way to express

$P(B|\overline A)\text{ using }P(B|A)$ ?

$P$ meaning probability

Comment: my text was bad formatted here is the good one: P(B/ complementary(A))

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Note that you can edit your own question to improve the formatting (for which you can in particular use MathJaX). Further more, can you give more context for your question?

Comment: It depends on what else you use. But knowing $\Pr(B|A)$ does not, by itself, tell us anything about  $\Pr(B|\overline{A})$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my bad i was working it out wrongly as well.

from $P(A|B^c)$ we could not get any direct formula to $P(A|B)$ but you can get a direct formula to $P(B|A^c)$ using [Bayes Theorm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem#Alternative_form).

Comment: thank you, Bayes theorem is exactly what i expected  for my calculus.  best regards,   Damien